# React-circular-progressBar not showing initialAnimation

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a progressBar component. The initial animation refuses to work in spite of setting initialAnimation to true. What am I missing?
Are there any extra CSS needed to fix it?
I just want the initialAnimation on the graph and number need not change

```
import React from 'react'
import CircularProgressbar from 'react-circular-progressbar'
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

const styles = theme => ({
    progressBar: {
      width: '80px',
      margin: 'auto',
      marginTop: theme.spacing.unit + 4,
      marginBottom: theme.spacing.unit + 4,
      position: 'relative'
    },
    text: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 20,
        left: 5,
        paddingRight: '5px' 
    }
  });

function StyledProgressbar(props) {
  const { classes, palette } = props;
  return (
    <div className={classes.progressBar}>
      <Typography variant="caption" align='center' className={classes.text}>
        {props.percentage}% complete
      </Typography>
      <CircularProgressbar
        percentage={props.percentage}
        strokeWidth={10}
        initialAnimation={true}
        styles={{
        path: {
            stroke: palette.secondary.main,
            strokeLinecap: 'round',
            transition: 'stroke-dashoffset 0.5s ease 0s',
        },
        trail: {
            stroke: palette.secondary.light,
            strokeLinecap: 'round',
        }
        }}>
      </CircularProgressbar>
    </div>
  );
}

StyledProgressbar.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object,
  percentage: PropTypes.number,
  palette: PropTypes.object
}

export default withStyles(styles)(StyledProgressbar);
```

Comment: "Version 2.0.0 replaces percentage with value and removes the initialAnimation prop." From https://github.com/kevinsqi/react-circular-progressbar#props

Comment: I did this a while ago and have  "react-circular-progressbar": "^1.0.0", in my package.json. It was working before. It should not break because I did not upgrade

Comment: If it was working before, then what change caused it to stop working?

Answer (score 1):

you just need to change this:

```
import CircularProgressbar from 'react-circular-progressbar';
```

from this:

```
import { CircularProgressbar } from 'react-circular-progressbar';
```

for more information [refrence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-circular-progressbar)